# Regular Expression If-Then-Else Condition

Tags: regex

I have a field, where a user can search for something. They should be able to search for `^[0-9a-zA-Z*]$`.

But it is not possible to search just for the character `*` (wildcard). There must be at least one other letter or number. `a* or *a or 1* or *1` is valid.

So there must be at least one number/letter unequal `*` for a valid search.

I think it should be realizable with the if/then/else condition. Here is my attempt!

```
"^(?(?=[*])([0-9a-zA-Z:\]{1,})|([0-9a-zA-Z:\*]*))$"
if character = *
then [0-9a-zA-Z:\]{1,} = user has to enter at least one (or more) characters of the group
else = [0-9a-zA-Z:\*]* = user has to enter 0 or more characters of the group
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: try **[this](https://regex101.com/r/rF4wZ8/1)** if lookaheads are supported in your regex

Comment: Or [`^[0-9a-zA-Z*]*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z*]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/eW7wD6/1).

Comment: `^(?!\*$)[0-9a-zA-Z*]$` should do. Alternatively, `^[0-9a-zA-Z*]*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z*]*$`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z*]*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z*]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eW7wD6/1)

This regex will match zero or more letters/digits/asterisks, then an obligatory letter or digit, and then zero or more letters/digits/asterisks.

Alternatively, you can require a string to have at least 1 letter or digit:

```
^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z*]+$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ4lE7/1). The `^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])` positive lookahead will require a letter or a digit after zero or more any characters but a newline. It can also be written as `^(?=.*\p{Alnum})[\p{Alnum}*]+$` (with double escaping backslash in Java).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/e31SPx):

```
String rx = "(?=.*\\p{Alnum})[\\p{Alnum}*]+";
System.out.println("****".matches(rx));       // FALSE
System.out.println("*a**".matches(rx));       // TRUE
```